# .vec file is not created in the sample folder in open CV

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I am using open CV library, I have created positive image folder and negative image folder, text file has also been created which contains the path of images in the folder, following this link http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html
when i am trying to run the command

```
perl bin/createsamples.pl positives.txt negatives.txt samples 7 "opencv_createsamples -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 1.1 -maxyangle 1.1 maxzangle 0.5 -maxidev 40 -w 80 -h 40"
```

but nothing is created in samples folder as you can see in the screenshot. Can anybody help me?

[screenshot available here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OicPZ.png)

Comment: can you post some parts of your positives.txt and negatives.txt and tell us from where you are starting opencv_createsamples and where the images are located?

Comment: ./negative_images/000_580182_001.jpg something like this. The negative.txt contains the list of path of images

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command:
 perl bin/createsamples.pl positives.txt negatives.txt ./samples 1500\
   "opencv_createsamples -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 1.1\
   -maxyangle 1.1 maxzangle 0.5 -maxidev 40 -w 80 -h 40"

Just added ./ before samples as it was not getting the exact directory where to store .vec files.